# Win7 says 'The User Profile Service service failed the logon. User profile cannot be loaded'

Tags: windows-7, windows, login, user-profiles

I've done some googling on this, and it looks like everything is pointing towards a corrupt profile or SID. The issue is that in this instance it's a domain roaming profile, I've tried a brand new one, and the same profiles that won't log onto this computer work on others.

Works fine with my domain administrator account, and local administrator accounts.

I've tried removing the computer from the domain and re-adding it with no change.

Windows throws Event ID 1500 at time of login attempt:

> Windows cannot log you on because your profile cannot be loaded. Check
>   that you are connected to the network, and that your network is
>   functioning correctly.
>
> DETAIL - Only part of a ReadProcessMemory or WriteProcessMemory
>   request was completed.

Comment: Roaming profile as in the profile is a remote profile and loaded at the time of logon?  Have you deleted the registry items related to the users that cannot logon and also delete their folders?

Comment: @Tim Yes, the profiles live on a network drive. The thing is, these users I'm trying to log in have never logged onto the computer before. So there's no profile information to delete. This is the confusing part of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem (not being able to log in with a new domain user account), it ended up being my disk at capacity and couldn't write a new profile. My default profile size was huge due to an install, made the profile size 12GB. Reduced it to 2GB and was able to login with a new userID. Hope this help!